# Cavy home question

Tags: psychology, guinea-pigs, enclosure

Hi  I've a 16 sq ft cage for my 2 cavies and I've an old tin dollhouse (22 inches wide x 11 inches deep) that I'd like to sit inside the cage, along with other toys and chews, as a hidey hut. I'm using a felt playmat with a road map design. Will this be harmful in any way to my cavies? or will they enjoy it?

Answer (score 2):

Tin will be tricky: They  WILL bite into it, and the edges will be sharp. So, keep the tin-house away from them.
Also, as a side-note, keep in mind that ALL houses you have in the cage will need 2 exits at least.

The felt-mat is to be the floor for your cage? The mat itself should not be hurtful, but it will need a LOT of cleaning. That's what kept me from going felt-based for mine.  With no bedding on top, expect a full washing about every 2 or 3 days.

If it is an outside play-mat, just clean as needed, depending on their playmat-time.

Oh, and: Congratulations, on actually having an actually decently sized cage!!! All too rare, sadly.